# Why is it removing CUDA when I am removing mate desktop?

Tags: apt, cuda, mate

I am trying to remove mate desktop and get

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mate-desktop                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                             
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                  
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                         
Package 'mate-desktop' is not installed, so not removed                                                                                   
The following packages will be REMOVED:                                                                                                   
  cuda-11-0 cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 cuda-compiler-11-0 cuda-cudart-11-0    
  ...
```

But why is it removing irrelevant libraries?

Answer (score 2):

From the output of `man apt-get` [under](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) the `--autoremove` option:

> If the command is either install or remove, then this option acts like running the autoremove command, removing unused dependency packages.

Those cuda packages were just waiting for an autoremove to come along, nothing to do with the Mate Desktop.  So the real question was did you really want to remove them?  Intel tends to hook all sorts of dependencies on their cuda packages, like depending upon the Nvidia driver package (which may be old), so when that get replaced, bingo -- all sorts of unwanted removes and autoremoves may gets triggered.